# MVC Form Error - Result Storage capacity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

We have a simple MVC form that allows user to register a product. Some user are reporting the following error when posting the form (this seems to be random with the majority of the form posts being ok).

[image]

We are using nopcommerce which normally logs all error but we have nothing showing in the logs.

I am unable to recreate the error in my dev enviroment and i'm not sure what it relates to.

The site is host on Azure.

Comment: Are you using any third party control?

Comment: Yes, We have added google captcha to the form

Comment: Nope, I mean are you using any plugin? Could you show some code!

Comment: Possibly this problem related to database server storage capacity or caching (since your form seems able to handle multiple submit requests from elsewhere). By seeing the message context, at random times assigned physical space for receiving requests may reach its limit and requiring a few moments to refresh.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto It would point to something like this but we aren't using anything out of the ordinary.... The site is hosted on Azure using SQL Azure as the DB